# How do I reverse the direction of arrows in my python anytree graphviz output?

Tags: python, graphviz, dot, anytree

I am building trees that are designed to represent a flow from leaves to the root of the tree using the anytree package in python.  I have the following code.

```
from anytree import Node
from anytree.exporter import DotExporter
A = Node('A')
B = Node('B', parent = A)
C = Node('C', parent = A)
DotExporter(A).to_picture('example.png')
```

And it produces the following image.

[image]

I want to modify this image such that the arrows point in the opposite direction.
I know that in graphviz adding `[dir=back]` to an edge definition line will give me the result that I want. By running the following code:

```
for line in DotExporter(A):
    print(line)
```

I get the output:

```
digraph tree {
    "A";
    "B";
    "C";
    "A" -> "B";
    "A" -> "C";
}
```

But how do I modify the output of `DotExporter` from the anytree interface to add `[dir=back]` to the edge definition lines and reverse the direction of the arrows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the edge attributes defined for `Dot` by the `DotExporter` you need to change the `edgeattrfunc` attribute of `DotExporter` as such.

```
from anytree import Node
from anytree.exporter import DotExporter
A = Node('A')
B = Node('B', parent = A)
C = Node('C', parent = A)
DotExporter(A, edgeattrfunc = lambda node, child: "dir=back").to_picture('example.png')
```

Looking at the output, you now get:

```
for line in DotExporter(A, edgeattrfunc = lambda node, child: "dir=back"):
    print(line)
```

```
digraph tree {
    "A";
    "B";
    "C";
    "A" -> "B" [dir=back];
    "A" -> "C" [dir=back];
}
```

Which produces the following image.

[image]